# What is this syntax, and why does it work?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is this syntax, and why does it work?

```
const content : string = functionThatReturnsAString();
const blob = new Blob([content]);
```

What is this `[string]`?

What does it return, and for which Blob() constructor is it an acceptable argument?

---

Sorry for the simple question, but I'd managed to convince myself that something much more complicated must be going on. What with spread syntax, et al., theere are a lot of new overloads of [] and {} that I'm only beginning to get a grasp on, and I convinced myself this was one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an array literal with one item, composed of `content`. It's the same as

```
const content : string = functionThatReturnsAString();
const arr = [];
arr.push(content);
const blob = new Blob(arr);
```

or

```
const content : string = functionThatReturnsAString();
const arr = [content];
const blob = new Blob(arr);
```

The [Blob constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) accepts as arguments:

```
new Blob(array, options);
```

so the string must be put into an array first.

Comment: So you can build a Blob with an array of strings, but not with a single string? That's not the way I would have designed the API. Thanks.